# If a function $\xi : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, it is constant on each element of the partition $B_{i}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm reading an intro measure-theoretic probability theory text. Here are a couple of definitions that I just read:

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. A function $\xi :
>  \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be
> *$\mathcal{F}$-measurable* if $\{\omega : a \leq \xi(\omega) < b\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for each $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

To be honest, this definition doesn't really make much sense to me. I tried looking at other resources; however, most of their definitions seemed to differ (other definitions usually had two measurable spaces rather than one), and I'm having trouble getting a good intuition for this type of thing.

The book also talks about how we can always partition an algebra into pairwise disjoint sets whose union equals $\Omega$ and any other set in the algebra can be constructed by the union of some of these sets.

This theorem is stated below:

> **Theorem:** If an algebra $\mathcal{G}$ is finite, then there exist non-empty sets $B_{1}, \ldots, B_{m}$ such that
>
> i) $B_{i} \cap B_{j} = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$
>
> ii) $\Omega = \cup_{i=1}^{m} B_{m}$
>
> iii) For any set $C \in \mathcal{G}$, there is a set $I\subseteq \{1, \ldots, m\}$ such that $C = \cup_{i \in I} B_{i}$ (with the convention that $C = \emptyset$ if $I = \emptyset$).

The book then makes a remark, saying that this implies that the sets $B_{i}$ for $1 \leq i \leq m$ define a partition of $\Omega$, and that finite algebras are generated by finite partitions.

Now I'm also having trouble following this theorem, which comes right after this definition:

> **Theorem:** If $\xi$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, then it takes a constant value on each element of the partition $B_{i}, 1 \leq i \leq
>  m$.
>
> **Proof:** Suppose $\xi$ takes at least two values, $a$ and $b$ with $a < b$ on the set $B_{j}$ for some $1 \leq j \leq m$. The set
> $\{\omega : a \leq \xi(\omega) < (a + b)/2\}$ must contain at least
> one point from $B_{j}$, yet it does not contain the entire set $B_{j}$
> (Why is this previous statement true? I can't figure that out). Thus,
> it cannot be represented as the union of some of the $B_{i}$ (why is
> this true?), which contradicts the $\mathcal{F}$-measurability of the
> set.

---

I am new to measure theoretic probability theory, and I am self-studying, so I would really appreciate some clarification to these concepts.

Thanks so much

Comment: I don't believe your question defines $B_j$ anywhere?

Comment: Also: the "real" definition of a measurable function is as follows: if $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ are both measurable spaces, then $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is measurable iff, for all $B\in\mathcal{B}$, it holds that $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{A}$. It turns out you can prove that this is equivalent to the "definition" you have given, which probabilists prefer because it is easier to check in practice.

Comment: You are right. I didn't define $B_{j}$. I just edited the post Also , okay. That makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of measurability you posted is a special case of the more general definition. By convention, the codomain of $\xi$, namely $\mathbb R$, is equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. It is generated by the half-open intervals $[a,b)$, and it is a general fact that one need verify measurability only on a generating family of sets for the $\sigma$-algebra to deduce that it holds for all measurable sets. Note that the set $\{\omega\colon a\leq \xi(\omega)<b\}$ can also be written as $\xi^{-1}([a,b))$, and this is the connection between the definition you posted and the more general definitions you have seen.

The first theorem you posted is stating that every **finite** $\sigma$-algebra is equivalent to a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable taking finitely many values. Indeed, the partition $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^m$ is equivalent to specifying a random variable $X\colon\Omega\to \{1,\ldots,m\}$ with $B_i=X^{-1}(i)$. As a side note, I will remark that understanding this result is somewhat orthogonal to the task of understanding measure theoretic probability, whose primary purpose was to solve some of the set-theoretic issues arising from a naive approach to uncountable events. In general, measurability issues do not arise in the setting of finite measure spaces.

Addressing your questions in the proof of the second theorem: first, since $\xi$ takes the value $a$ somewhere on the set $B_j$ this necessarily means (and is equivalent to) $\xi^{-1}(a)\cap B_j$ being non-empty, and this set is contained in the one you are interested in (hence it contains at least one point from $B_j$). By the same reasoning, $\xi^{-1}(b)\cap B_j$ is also non-empty, and any point in that set is an example of a point in $B_j$ not in the set you are interested in. Hence the set contains at least one point from $B_j$ but not every point from $B_j$. Second, any set of the form $T=\cup_{j\in S}B_j$ for $S\subseteq \{1,\ldots,m\}$ has the property that either $B_j$ is entirely contained in $T$ (if $j\in S$) or otherwise $B_j$ is disjoint from $T$ (if $j\not\in S$). Thus, no such set $T$ has the property exhibited by the previous sentence, and hence the set in question cannot be written as a union of elements of the partition.

In summary, the terminology of measure-theoretic probability has several equivalent formulations, all of which give a rigorous structure for probabilistic reasoning. In the finite setting you are asking about here, there are no measurability concerns, but only terminology concerns. Keep slogging through it and you will eventually absorb/learn the language, and later you will come to the more interesting parts of the beautiful subject of continuous probability.